# parallel payment or chained payment

Tags: php, paypal

how we send the payment in two users account on single click, I want to do payment to the freelancer and admin on same time and single click.

example: I have $3000,I want to pay $2000 to freelancer and $1000 to admin in single click.

```
<?php if ($data['accept_freelancer_status1'] == "1") { ?>
    <td> 
        <br>
        <br>&nbsp;

        <?php
        $mode = "sandbox";  //live
        $admin_email = "busineess_mail";

        if ($mode == "sandbox") {
            $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        } else {
            $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        }
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AW72MA4XCQTSA">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $admin_email; ?>">
            <!--<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="First Amount">-->
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $data['project_id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo ($this->session_user_detail['user_id']); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $pending_payment; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<?php echo $data['project_id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo main_url; ?>/calculation_fst_success">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo main_url; ?>/cancel">
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="">
            <!--<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">-->
            <?php if ($data['client_step1'] == "1") { ?>
                <p style="    margin-top: -52px;">First Step Complete</p>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php if ($data['frst_payment_dn'] == "1") { ?>
                    <p style="    padding: 8px 7px;
                       background-color: #95D195;
                       color: #fff;
                       border-radius: 9px;margin-top: -60px;    width: 160px;" >
                        <span style="color:#000;" >First Payment Complete </span>check this box and notify to the freelancer</p>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="margin-top: -52px;
                            ">Pay now</button>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adaptive Payments API enables you to send money in many different scenarios, from simple to complex.

Adaptive payments handles payments between a sender of a payment and one or more receivers of the payment. You are an application owner, such as a merchant that owns a website, the owner of a widget on a social networking site, the provider of a payment application on mobile phones, and so on. Your application is the caller of Adaptive Payments API operations.

Answer (score 0):

hlo budy. 
A chained payment is a payment from a sender that is indirectly split among multiple receivers. It is an extension of a typical payment from a sender to a receiver, in which a receiver, known as the primary receiver, passes part of the payment to other receivers, who are called secondary receivers.
and

Parallel payments enable a sender to send a single payment to multiple receivers. For example, your application might be a shopping cart that enables a buyer to pay for items from several merchants with one payment. Your shopping cart allocates the payment to merchants that actually provided the items. PayPal then deducts money from the sender's account and deposits it in the receivers' accounts.